# Inconsistency in Maven command line build versus Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm attempting to upgrade the JDK version used by my project to JDK 8.  I have installed Eclipse Luna (4.4.1), and set the JDK compiler compliance level to 1.8.  I also modified the maven-compiler-plugin's configuration to use source and target versions of 1.8:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Eclipse builds my entire project successfully, and indicates that I have no compile time errors in my project. However, when I run `mvn clean install` from the command line, I receive a compiler error:

`SomeClass.java:[91,89] incompatible types: inference variable B has incompatible bounds`

Is there any reason I'd see this error from the command line, but not Eclipse?  Eclipse is pointing to the same maven installation being used from the command line.

Output from `mvn -version`:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T11:37:52-06:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.1
Java version: 1.8.0_31, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite odd indeed.

I believe you could try something like this in your pom, just to make sure:

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>  
</properties>
```

Are you sure that that eclipse is pointing to the same maven installation? I would check it again, just to play safe.

[Or it might be a bug.](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8043926)

Comment: Looks like it is a bug in the JDK.  I upgraded to the early-release version of JDK 1.8.0_40 and the compilation succeeds!  Thanks a lot, I would've been stuck on that for quite a while.